# ffmpeg convert a series of images to video - with crossfade or any other transition between every two frames

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, transition, cross-fade

I am currently able to convert a series of images to video, but I do also need to add transitions / animation in between them.

```
String[] ffmpegCommand = {"/data/data/mypackage/app_bin/ffmpeg", "-y",
"-qscale", "1", "-r", "" + framerate, "-i", "/data/data/mypackage/app_ipImg/image%3d.jpg",
"-t", "" + (((total_images) * delay_of_each_frame_in_seconds) + 4), //"-s",heightwidth,
"-vcodec", "libx264", "-s", "640x480",
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/photo_directory/myVideo.mp4"};
```

**The above command is working for me to create video from image series**

**But**

**Now, I do want to add fade or other transition / animation to be displayed in final video before each of the frames**.

I googled a lot, but didn't find any solution to this trouble, yet.

Please suggest me the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I am also able to create video from a set of pictures but cant seem to apply any effects to it. Please let me know if you've figured out a way to do this.

Comment: @San Nope. I did not.

Comment: See [Create video from images with fade in/out or crossfade effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/834035).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to find more information about **Frame Blending** or **Motion interpolation**.

This is for example used in timelapse videos to smooth the render.

- To *blend frames*, use ffmpeg with the tblend filter.
  For example the following command can help :
  `ffmpeg -i {input} -vf "tblend=average,framestep=2,setpts=0.50*PTS" -r {srcfps} -{encoding parameters} {output}`. Replace `{input}` by your input file, `{output}` by the name of the output file, `{srcfps}` by your source frames per second, and `-{encoding parameters}` the parameters you tell ffmpeg to output.
  You could also add `minterpolate` filter to the filter stack to add some motion blur.
- To *generate new frames* based on motion, the Butterflow project can help : https://github.com/dthpham/butterflow

  > **Features**
  >
  > Makes **motion interpolated videos** (increase a video's frame rate by rendering intermediate frames based on motion, uses a combination of pixel-warping and blending).
  >
  > Makes **smooth motion videos** (simple blending between frames).
  >
  > Leverages interpolated frames to make **fluid slow motion videos**.

Comment: This does not do any kind of transition between images

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches

1) Create a video for each image/slide and add the fade-in fade-out to each one, then add the videos together. This [link](http://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_fade_in_fade_out_transitions_effects_filters.php) explains how to create a fade effect for images.

2) Use the a mixture of filters along with the -loop option as explained in [this link](https://superuser.com/a/834035).

Comment: Talking about your first approach ---- is there any command to generate video for each image by providing the image sequence only....or do I need to do it manually for each image one by one?

Comment: Also, I guess, the first approach will not help in making cross-fade transitions, wt do you suggest?

Comment: For the first one, I think you do need to do it manually. For the cross-fade (if I undertand correctly what it means) you may have to play with the images Alpha (transparency) and overlay them http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1